# What's this repeating area in the original Zelda?

Tags: virtual-console, the-legend-of-zelda

I was playing the Switch virtual console edition of Zelda I, and I found some area near the bottom left of the overworld map. It looks like it's a plus-shaped walkway with Moblins and it seems to be going on forever.

I checked a map online, and my guess is when I leave the screen into the loading zone, it puts me back at the start of that room.

Is this an intended feature of the game, or is it a bug in the switch's virtual console?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's the maze I'm thinking of, you need to go through it in a special order.
North -> West -> South -> West

This video shows it:

Comment: First iteration of the Lost Woods.

Comment: Also known as "The Forest of Maze" according to the old woman who gives you the NWSW clue